# How can I read all users using keycloak and spring in openshift?

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, keycloak

[image]

here i am trying to get a list with users from keycloak.
it works withe docker compose, but not in openshift?!

my application.property

```
keycloak.enabled=true
keycloak.realm=somname
keycloak.ssl-required=none
keycloak.resource=someapp
keycloak.public-client=true

keycloak.auth-server-url=${KEYCLOAK_AUTH-SERVER-URL:https://localhost/auth}
keycloak.disable-trust-manager=true

app.connectors.KeyCloakAdminConnector.serverUri=${KEYCLOAK_ADMIN-URL:http://idm.local:8081/auth}
app.connectors.KeyCloakAdminConnector.realm=${keycloak.realm}
app.connectors.KeyCloakAdminConnector.username=admin
app.connectors.KeyCloakAdminConnector.password=pass
app.connectors.KeyCloakAdminConnector.clientId=${keycloak.resource}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution i changed the:

```
 keycloak-admin-url: 'my-keycloak-route/auth'
```

in application.property to

```
keycloak-admin-url: 'http://myservice-keycloak-http:8080/auth'
```

so i change the connection between the Spring boot App and Keycloack from Rout-Object to a Service-Object.

its works because Service is not https. so i dont need to provide a certificate to JVM keytrust in the Spring boot App